# Accessing the value of a Java array position by index

Tags: java, arrays

I'm really new to Java and am just struggling with arrays a little bit. I've got a block of code that I've written when following a tutorial but am struggling to understand it and would love if someone could explain it to me.

I've tried working through it with various different methods (explaining to my duck, writing it down, etc.) and still can't get my head around it. I normally wouldn't ask and I always try desperately hard to work it out myself, but I just can't figure it out this time.

```
int[] values = new int[3];

values[0] = 10;
values[1] = 20;
values[3] = 30;

for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(values[i]);
}
```

I understand why:

1. The for loop iterates through the values in "values".
2. The loop keeps looping until i is less than the last value in the array.

But what I don't understand is why I need to write `values[i]` in the `System.out.println()` statement. What tells Java that `i` can be used in the array `values[]`?

Sorry if this is a trivial question for you but this is the best place I could think of to turn.

Comment: Do you really have a pet duck? :O

Comment: Because the square brackets `[index]` accesses the element of the array at the `index`.

Comment: You'll get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` on row `values[3] = 30;`, since `3` points to 4th array element.

Comment: There's an error in the 3rd assignment. It should be `values [2]` instead of `values[3]`, because Java arrays are 0-indexed and so an index of 3 indicates the 4th array elegant, which dies not exist as `values` was assigned to be a 3-element array, and otherwise you would get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

Java knows that *values* is an array type. Arrays in Java are indexed by integers, so here we have an integer called *i*. *i* goes from 0 to less than *values.length* (in this case is 3). So i will be 0, 1, and 2.

Indexing *values* with 0, 1, and 2 are equivalent to:

```
values[0]
values[1]
values[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JAVA is not a mind reader, unless you tell java value of which index you want to print JAVA will not be able to understand :)

So you have mention index like `values[0]` ,`values[1]` etc

Answer (score 0):

`values` is the array name and 'i' is the index.
`values[0]` will print *10*. `values[1]` will print *20*.

Refer these links for more information:

- http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_arrays.html
- http://www.javatpoint.com/array-in-java

Also learn how to debug the java code.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain in a simple way:
As soon as you use the statement:

```
int[] values = new int[3];
```

and assign values to it there will be three blocks of memory of integer size in memory.

as `i` is initialized to zero and each iteration in the `for` loop,
will execute the statement `System.out.println(values[i]);`

It will just substitute current value of `i` in `values[i]` that is `values[0]` for first round etc.

So it will check for already assigned values in the memory I talked about earlier and print it.

Answer (score 0):

The `System.out.println(values[i]);` Tells the system to print the value at the given index in the array.

If we say `System.out.println(values[0]);`, the value at index 0 which is 10 is printed.

To print out all the values in the array, instead of typing the index for each value manually like values[1], values[2]. We use a for statement `for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)` creates a variable `i` and assigns it a value `0`, so on the first run through the loop,`values[i]` is `values[0]`.

After the first run through the loop, the `i` is incremented from 0 to 1 because of the `i++` part of the for statement. on the second run `values[i]` is `values[1]` and what is printed is the value at index 1 which is 20. This continues as long as `i < values.lenght;` returns true.